# Grandient colors in each serie(line) Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

Does someone know if i could make a 3 dimensions chart but by using a regular 2D line chart such as linear chart but the 3rd axis would be represented by a gradient color onto the serie's line:
If the 3rd dimension is high with a hot color (color of the line) and if it is low with a cold color (for example).

Thank everyone for the help. Excuse my lack of knowledge, I'm beginning...

In addition: 
These two graphs are made from these points:

[x y z]

1st section

[1, 2, 10]

[6, 4, 6]

2nd section

[6, 4, 6]

[10, 3, 4]

3rd section

[3, 10, 13]

[6, 4, 6]

4th section

[10, 3, 4]

[13, 13, -6]

[X&Y graph and X&Z graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdNN7.png)

Well, what I'd like to do is represent just the first graph (X&Y) and the Z coordinate represented by a gradient color kind of [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXOpV.png) gradient but within the lines. Instead those default colors.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  It is helpful to provide source code of what you have rather than ask vague questions.  If you could at least post your data (structure) and the 2 dimensional line chart, it would help provide direction.

Comment: Maybe you have a picture of your chart?

Comment: I hope now it is more complete because I don't know how I could explain it better... No including the whoooooole code hehe. 
Thank you all